# How to create a pull request after authentication using Github Enterprise API?

Tags: github, github-api

I have written a shell script to create a pull request with Github Enterprise API.

```
#!/bin/sh
CURRENT_BRANCH=$(git branch --show-current)
git stash save
git checkout master
git pull
UUID=$(uuidgen)
git checkout -b "${UUID}"
npm version patch
git add package.json
git commit -m "#; update version script test"
git push origin "${UUID}"
curl -u [MY_USER_NAME]:[MY_TOKEN] https://github.[MY_ORGANIZATION].com/api/v3/user
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://github.[MY_ORGANIZATION].com/api/v3/repos/Modules/[MY_REPO]/pulls \
  -d "{'head':'${UUID}','base':'master'}"
```

The log is displayed as below.
It fail to create the pull request with the error

> "message": "Must authenticate to access this API."

However, there seems no issue with the authentication.

```
// omit some useless log here
remote:
To github.microstrategy.com:Modules/mstr-web-hierarchy.git
 * [new branch]      23CFA0E3-33D1-489E-9E55-D38F92BB1B99 -> 23CFA0E3-33D1-489E-9E55-D38F92BB1B99
{
  "login": "shizhang",
  "id": 1191,
  // some useless properties here
{
  "message": "Must authenticate to access this API.",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/enterprise/3.0/rest"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `curl` does not seem to include any [authentication information](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api#authentication).

Try adding the same `-u [MY_USER_NAME]:[MY_TOKEN]` as you used in the first `curl`.

In other words, the first curl success does not mean other curls would benefit from an authenticated session.

---

> Problems parsing JSON

Try with a simpler JSON, just for testing.
And pay attention to quotes: '${UUID}' would not be expanded, and would remain exactly as `'${UUID}'`.
See "[How to include environment variable in bash line CURL?](https://superuser.com/a/835589/141)"

Comment: It does not wrok. An error message is thrown: {
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/enterprise/3.0/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request"
}

Comment: @A.Chao I agree but the original issue in your question was: ""Must authenticate to access this API.". I have answered that question.

Comment: @A.Chao I have edited the answer to address your error message, with a suggestion regarding the `'${UUID}'` part of your JSON payload.